# Locate planets and stars for beginners

Tags: star, planet, telescope

I am a beginner in astronomy. In fact, I just bought my first refractor telescope with 60 mm aperture and 600 focal lengths with 4mm, 12.5mm and 20 mm eyepiece and 3x barlow.

Could I get info on android app or book where I can see real-time position of planets and other amazing celestial bodies, I am in the northern hemisphere.

Comment: Hi sudhirk, you can improve this question by showing a little prior research. Its fairly easy to search for [android apps and planetarium software](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sky%20map), and any of the apps would probably suit your needs.

Comment: I did few but did not help much. Thanks. Will look for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of apps you can download on your laptop / smartphone :

- Stellarium : the one i use on my computer. Useful for beginners. You will see planets, some of the best known object, ...
- Skymap for android : used it before, quite nice.
- SkySafari : don't use it but some people told me it was great.

All of them are free. However, you can just search on google, there are plenty of online solutions.

Comment: SkySafari  seemed to be good one